# Python - Counting Unique Labels in a Date Range

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm attempting to perform sentiment analysis on a pile of text data I have scraped from the internet. I have reached a point where my Pandas DataFrame has the following columns I wish to analyse: "post_date" (in the format dd-mm-yyyy ie. 01-10-2017) & "Sentiment" (in the format "positive","neutral" or "negative").

I wish to be able to count the number of posts by each day/month/year and also the number of positive/neutral/negative posts for each day.

for example like those produced by:

```
print pd.value_counts(df.Sentiment)
```

However I am stuck, i've tried many iterations of the groupby command (below), but keep coming up with errors.

```
df.groupby(df.post_date.dt.year)
```

Could anyone please help with how I can achieve this?

Ideally the desired output would be something like:

```
Date, Postive_Posts, Negative_Posts, Neutral_Posts, Total_Posts
01/10/2017, 10, 5, 8, 23
02/10/2017, 5, 20, 5, 30
```

Where date is how the information has been grouped (day, month, year, etc.), and the pos/neg/neu columns are the total posts corresponding to the count of the labels in that range, finally total_posts is the total count of posts in that range.

the data is currently:

```
post_date, Sentiment
19/09/2017, positive
19/09/2017, positive
19/09/2017, positive
20/09/2017, negative
20/09/2017, neutral
```

Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: Can you add data sample and desired output?

Comment: @jezrael I have updated the post, I hope it makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) + [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) + [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['post_date','Sentiment']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).add_suffix('_Posts')
df1['Total_Posts'] = df1.sum(axis=1)
print (df1)

Sentiment   negative_Posts  neutral_Posts  positive_Posts  Total_Posts
post_date                                                             
19/09/2017               0              0               3            3
20/09/2017               1              1               0            2
```

One line solution is very similar - only need [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['post_date','Sentiment'])
        .size()
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .add_suffix('_Posts')
        .assign(Total_Posts=lambda x: x.sum(axis=1)))

print (df1)

Sentiment   negative_Posts  neutral_Posts  positive_Posts  Total_Posts
post_date                                                             
19/09/2017               0              0               3            3
20/09/2017               1              1               0            2
```

And for column from `index`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['post_date','Sentiment'])
        .size()
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .add_suffix('_Posts')
        .assign(Total_Posts=lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

print (df1)

    post_date  negative_Posts  neutral_Posts  positive_Posts  Total_Posts
0  19/09/2017               0              0               3            3
1  20/09/2017               1              1               0            2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly! is it possible to also sort by the post date? currently it is displaying all 01 for example:

 Sentiment   negative_Posts  neutral_Posts  positive_Posts  Total_Posts
    post_date                                                             
    01-01-2014               0              0               3            3
    01-01-2015               1              1               0            2

Comment: I think the best is before set to datetime by `df['post_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['post_date'])`

Comment: Only change I had to make was added (dayfirst=True) to the .to_datetime